# Interpreting QQ plot (Normal vs Heavy-tailed)

Tags: normal-distribution, qq-plot, heavy-tailed

I'm having some trouble interpreting the shape of this distribution. It is a distribution of price differences between an estimate and actual price. There are 219 points. I'm not sure if I can call it Gaussian or if it is heavy tailed or light tailed. The shapiro-wilk test for normality gave me a significant p-value of 1.96e^-5. While the KS-test(using a second normal distribution with he same mean and sd) gave me an insignificant p-value. (0.14). How an I go about finding a an appropriate distribution this can be described with?
[image]

Comment: You should search the site & read some of the existing threads on these topics.  There are *a lot*.  In addition, can you clarify why you need to know if the distribution is normal?

Comment: I've tried reading through a lot of them. It's just that my distribution is extra peculiar to me. If I can prove that it is non Gaussian or heavy tail like it will help relate it t the financial landscape from which it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

The null hypothesis for a Shapiro-Wilk test
is that the population from which a sample was randomly sampled has *some* normal distribution (parameters unspecified). By contrast, $H_0$ for our Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is that the population
is normal with specified $\mu$ and $\sigma.$ (If you estimate $\mu$ by $\bar X$ and $\sigma$ by $S,$ the P-value needs to be adjusted.)

Here is an example of normal Q-Q plots and tests
for samples of size $n=250$ from normal and [heavy tailed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) $\mathsf{T}(\nu=2)$ distributions. Because you show a Q-Q plot with Sample Quantiles on the
vertical axis (default in R), that is the type of Q=Q plots I show.

**Moderate sample size.** We use $n=250$ here because formal tests for
various distributions may be at their best for
such moderate sample sizes.

- The S-W, and especially the K-S test, may have very poor power for small
  sample sizes.
- Also, in practice with huge samples, these tests may too 'readily' reject
  a (nearly) normal sample as being non-normal because of
  some small quirk that is not of practical importance.

**Normal data.** The sample is of moderate size
so the tests work well. Neither S-W nor K-S for
$\mathsf{Norm}(0.1) rejects.

```r
set.seed(1234)
z = rnorm(250)  # standard normal
summary(z);  sd(z)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-3.233152 -0.657095 -0.043433 -0.004079  0.623527  3.043766 
[1] 1.017413  # sample SD
shapiro.test(z)$p.val
[1] 0.1382135         # Not Rejected (correct)
ks.test(z, pnorm, 0,1)$p.val
[1] 0.7156302         # Not Rejected (correct)
```

**Heavy-tailed** $\mathsf{T}(\nu=2)$ population.
This distribution has such heavy tails that it has
no variance (or standard deviation), so we do not
show its sample standard deviation in the summary.
Notice max and min both far from $\mu=0.$

```r
u = rt(250, 2)
summary(u)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-12.75136  -0.70875   0.05952   0.19331   0.93226  20.32579
```

The S-W test strongly rejects the sample as non-normal, the K-S barely rejects the sample as
not from $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$ The K-S test [based on the CDF of $\mathsf{T}(2)]$correctly fails to reject the population as sampled from this heavy-tailed distribution.

```r
shapiro.test(u)$p.val
[1] 3.118322e-19       # Strongly Rejected (correct)

ks.test(u, pnorm, 0,1)$p.val
[1] 0.02851291         # Barely Rejected (correct)

ks.test(u, pt, 2)$p.val
[1] 0.1142186          # Not Rejected (correct)
```

**Normal probability plots** of the two samples. Many statisticians prefer to judge normality "by eye," using Q-Q plots, rather than by using formal
tests.

One expects normal data to yield a "nearly" linear
pattern of points, perhaps staying near a reference line based on upper and lower quartiles. However,
in the tails were data is sparse one does not
expect the data points to follow the reference line
closely. There is no question that the sample
from the heavy-tailed distribution fails to yield
a "linear" plot.

[image]

R code for plots:

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 qqnorm(z, main="Normal")
  qqline(z, col="blue")
 qqnorm(u, main="T(2)")
  qqline(u, col="blue")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Finally, we show normal probability plots
for two additional samples of size 250 from
these same distributions.

```r
set.seed(1122)
z = rnorm(250);  u = rt(250, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Harold Jeffreys did an analysis of some real datasets in which measurement error was the main story and suggested that $t$ with $7$ df was a fairer approximation than normal. It's not easy to tell a normal and such a distribution apart with data.

Comment: @ NickCox. Thanks for that story.

Comment: @NickCox: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: The most accessible summary is in his _Theory of Probability_ (any edition 1939, 1948, 1961). Note that the title is not indicative of the contents. It is about a Bayesian approach to data analysis and inference.